# I don't know how to implement Material Design 3 in Android Studio.(Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, material-design

I'm a Junior Developer and I found out a couple weeks back what Material Design is.
I'm used to learn basic raw components that are given to me by Android Studio, and I want my apps to have Material Design components.

I've been searching all over the internet and found out some GitHub repositories, but I don't know how to implement it.

Can anyone tell me exactly what Material Design is and how to implement it on Android Studio suitable for Kotlin.

Thanks.

I tried going to this repository on GitHub,

**https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android**

but it's in Java and I don't have yet an idea of what Material Design is and how to implement it, if I can implement it or if it comes by default on Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Step # 1

Add dependency in `build.gradle(app)`, latest Android Studio now have it by default.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Step # 2

For Material3, update both of your `theme.xml` & `theme.xml(night)` as follow:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Step # 3

Start using Material components, have a look at this official [link](https://m3.material.io/components).

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Comment: still don't get how to implement it, I've already come across this website but when I have all the dependencies I don't know how to implement it!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6lDVQ8aBRc&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcSxDB7LTgNf5k_PD3gIs5hD&index=8
Please view this link to learn from basics